# ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 14: v_result := SELECT * FROM iis_e_ack_pkg.is_e_ack_confirm

Tags: postgresql-9.5

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION iis_e_ack_pkg.is_e_ack_confirm ( vi_record_id text, vi_business_type text, vo_note_type INOUT text ) AS $body$
DECLARE

    v_result varchar(1) := 'N';
    v_note_type varchar(50) := '';
    v_ack_submit_date  varchar(50) := '';

BEGIN
    
    v_result := SELECT * FROM iis_e_ack_pkg.is_e_ack_confirm(vi_record_id, vi_business_type, vo_note_type, v_ack_submit_date) INTO STRICT vo_note_type, v_ack_submit_date;

    RETURN;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      v_result := 'N';
      RETURN;
  END;

$body$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
;
```

Comment: please check the issue need solutions.

Comment: Please check the code and provide at least some assistant.

Comment: Any help on this question ,kindly let me know.

Comment: any update regarding this.